# Problem with relation between 2 tables - in mysql can not add foreign key - in Laravel Property [xxx] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, pivot-table, laravel-8

I have 2 tables and a pivot table to handle the many-to-many relation.  I have to use the names of the tables as they are and Laravel adds _ the id names in the pivot table.

```
 TABLE sc_suscodes
     id primary big int unsigned
 TABLE t_users
      id_user primary big int unsigned
 TABLE sc_suscodes_users
      id
      t__user_id big int unsigned
      s_c__suscode_id big int unsigned
      
 ALTER TABLE `sc_suscode_user`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `scsuscodes-tusers` FOREIGN KEY (`s_c__scsuscode_id`) REFERENCES `sc_scsuscodes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
   ADD CONSTRAINT `tusers-scsuscodes` FOREIGN KEY (`t__user_id`) REFERENCES `t_users` (`id_user`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

In Laravel:

```
 USER MODEL
 // return all the suscodes associated with this user
 public function allSuscodes()
 {
      return $this->belongsToMany(SC_Suscode::class,'sc_suscode_user');
 }
 
 SC_SUSCODE MODEL
 / return all the users associated with this suscode
 public function allUsers()
 {
      return $this->belongsToMany(USER::class,'sc_suscode_user');
 }
 
 $codesIDs = USER::where('id_user','=',$user_id)->allSuscodes;
 
 ERROR... Property [allSuscodes] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

What is wrong?

What I do not understand is how Laravel knows that the id_user in t_users is related to the t__user_id in the pivot table?

Or should I rename t__user_id to t__user_id_user or t__user_id__user?

I have another pivot table that works perfectly well.

Comment: Adding constraints does not implicitly add the column. You need to add the column before you can declare a constraint on that column. This is necessary because you might need other column attributes on the column, like `NOT NULL` or `DEFAULT`, and there is no way to declare those only in a constraint.

Comment: @BillKarwin The table was setup correctly by defining all the fields.  The reason MySQL was initially giving an error is because t_users was MyISAM and the other tables InnoDB.  So the relation is set-up correctly in MySQL but I still get an error in Laravel.

Comment: You can't make a foreign key referencing a MyISAM table.

Comment: @BillKarwin I've learned that... but still issue in Laravel...

Comment: Can you alter the MyISAM table(s) to change their storage engine to InnoDB?

Comment: Did all the tables get declared _before_ adding the `CONSTRAINTs`?

Comment: @BillKarwin yes all tables are now InnoDB and there were fully declared b4 adding the constraints.  MySQL part is working 100%.  It is only the Laravel part that does not work (and it work with many other pivot tables I have).

Comment: Okay I misunderstood your title — "in mysql can not add foreign key". I do not know Laravel, so I will back away now... :-)